# Issue in SOAP API publishing in wso2 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

we are using wso2 3.0.0, I want to publish soap API for that I have WSDL of API and XSD, but there is the only the option to upload to WSDL I cant upload XSD, due to which validation getting failed, can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, you can do the either of following options. Generally external XSDs are imported in WSDL in following format.

```
<xsd:schema>
   <xsd:import namespace="xxxxxx" schemaLocation="schema.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

You can either,

1. specify the full path of the imported XSD file under `scehmaLocation` attribute.

OR

2. specify only the file name of the imported XSD file under `scehmaLocation` and copy the XSD file into the same directory where the WSDL file is located. If you are specifying any relative path, the XSD should be copied into the relevant file location.

You can also specify the location as URL if the XSD is hosted in a different server.

Comment: Getting Error:
[Fatal Error] :20:16: The prefix "xsd" for element "xsd:schema" is not bound.

Comment: The `xsd` part in the example provided is the namespace prefix. If you are using, you should define the namespace prefix in the WSDL file. can u attach the part of wsdl where the schema is imported?

Comment: I have given an example namespace prefix, you can use the prefix based on your WSDL file. In the case I provide, the namespace prefix is defined in the wsdl. The namespace can be defined by an xmlns attribute in the start tag of an element. For instance, `xsd` prefix is defined as ```<definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">``` in wsdl

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the latest APIM versions(3.2.0 or 3.1.0). You can upload a ZIP file with additional XSDs.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/6118

[2] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/7182

Comment: are you sure the zipping file will work? because I tried it still did not work

Comment: we are not using 3.2.0 using only 3.0.0

Comment: no this is not supported in 300. Support is added from 3.1.0 onward.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not supported in 300, You can modify the WSDL and define or include your XSDs inline. So that when parsing the WSDL, it will not search XSD in an external location.

Comment: can you give some reference regarding adding xsd to wsdl?

Comment: You can add XSD to the WSDL type section. Please refer to this(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_types.htm)